# Скрытие столбцов в таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Таблица

```
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>                            
</table>
```

при нажатие на checkbox скрывается столбец

```
<input name="column" type="checkbox" value="0" onClick="toggle_column('table', this.value);" checked />
<input name="column" type="checkbox" value="1" onClick="toggle_column('table', this.value);" checked />
<input name="column" type="checkbox" value="2" onClick="toggle_column('table', this.value);" checked />
```

script

```
 function toggle_column(table, column_nr) {
        table = document.getElementById('table');
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var row=0; row<rows.length;row++) {
            cels = rows[row].getElementsByTagName('td');
            cels[column_nr].style.display=cels[column_nr].style.display=="none" ? "" : "none";
        }
    }
```

Можно ли, как то сделать чтобы скрывались столбцы не по `value`, а по `id` или `class`, 
хочу применить к таблице такого вида

```
<table  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><?php echo $text_price ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $text_comment?></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $order['comment']?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете назначить ячейкам классы и по ним скрывать.
А в чекбоксах хранить названия этих классов.

Лучше отслеживать событие 'change' для чекбоксов.
И использовать CSS для скрытия колонки.

```js
const controls = document.getElementById('controls');
controls.addEventListener('change', e => {
  toggleColumn(e.target.dataset.columnClass);
});

function toggleColumn(columnClass) {
 const cells = document.querySelectorAll(`.${columnClass}`);
  
  cells.forEach(cell => {
   cell.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-1">Цена</th>
      <th class="col-2">Комментарий</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="col-1">200</td>
     <td class="col-2">БУ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="col-1">500</td>
     <td class="col-2">Новый</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="controls">
  <input type="checkbox" data-column-class="col-1" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" data-column-class="col-2" checked>
</div>
```